# Expandable GridView with view recycling in Android

Tags: android, gridview, expandable, collapsable

I am trying to implement a android activity where I have sections of items (for example car brands and their models).

I want to be able to display the items in a grid (e.g. fixed to 3 columns) and each of the grids can be collapsed. Actually I want exactly what the ExpandableList view does for ListViews but with a GridView.

Unfortunately if I return a GridView in the ExpandableListAdapter, the items inside this GridView won't be recycled as they are moving off the screen during scrolling. And we have a lot of items to display which would lead to serious memory issues.

How would I achieve something like that ?

Regards
Ben

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my reinvented wheel (A lot of code is copy-pasted from AOSP's GridView).

```
package ua.snuk182.expandablegrid;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewDebug;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ExpandableGridView extends ExpandableListView {

    /**
     * Disables stretching.
     * 
     * @see #setStretchMode(int)
     */
    public static final int NO_STRETCH = 0;
    /**
     * Stretches the spacing between columns.
     * 
     * @see #setStretchMode(int)
     */
    public static final int STRETCH_SPACING = 1;
    /**
     * Stretches columns.
     * 
     * @see #setStretchMode(int)
     */
    public static final int STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH = 2;
    /**
     * Stretches the spacing between columns. The spacing is uniform.
     * 
     * @see #setStretchMode(int)
     */
    public static final int STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM = 3;

    /**
     * Creates as many columns as can fit on screen.
     * 
     * @see #setNumColumns(int)
     */
    public static final int AUTO_FIT = -1;

    private int mNumColumns = AUTO_FIT;

    private int mHorizontalSpacing = 0;
    private int mRequestedHorizontalSpacing;
    private int mVerticalSpacing = 0;
    private int mStretchMode = STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH;
    private int mColumnWidth;
    private int mRequestedColumnWidth;
    private int mRequestedNumColumns;

    public ExpandableGridView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ExpandableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ExpandableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.ExpandableGridView, defStyle, 0);

        int hSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                R.styleable.ExpandableGridView_horizontalSpacing, 0);
        setHorizontalSpacing(hSpacing);

        int vSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                R.styleable.ExpandableGridView_verticalSpacing, 0);
        setVerticalSpacing(vSpacing);

        int index = a.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableGridView_stretchMode, STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
        if (index >= 0) {
            setStretchMode(index);
        }

        int columnWidth = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.ExpandableGridView_columnWidth, -1);
        if (columnWidth > 0) {
            setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
        }

        int numColumns = a.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableGridView_numColumns, 1);
        setNumColumns(numColumns);

        //I haven't dealt with gravity yet, so this is commented for now...
        /*index = a.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableGridView_gravity, -1);
        if (index >= 0) {
            setGravity(index);
        }*/

        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(new ExpandableGridInnerAdapter(adapter));
    }

    /**
     * Set the amount of horizontal (x) spacing to place between each item
     * in the grid.
     *
     * @param horizontalSpacing The amount of horizontal space between items,
     * in pixels.
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_horizontalSpacing
     */
    public void setHorizontalSpacing(int horizontalSpacing) {
        if (horizontalSpacing != mRequestedHorizontalSpacing) {
            mRequestedHorizontalSpacing = horizontalSpacing;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the amount of horizontal spacing currently used between each item in the grid.
     *
     * <p>This is only accurate for the current layout. If {@link #setHorizontalSpacing(int)}
     * has been called but layout is not yet complete, this method may return a stale value.
     * To get the horizontal spacing that was explicitly requested use
     * {@link #getRequestedHorizontalSpacing()}.</p>
     *
     * @return Current horizontal spacing between each item in pixels
     *
     * @see #setHorizontalSpacing(int)
     * @see #getRequestedHorizontalSpacing()
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_horizontalSpacing
     */
    public int getHorizontalSpacing() {
        return mHorizontalSpacing;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the requested amount of horizontal spacing between each item in the grid.
     *
     * <p>The value returned may have been supplied during inflation as part of a style,
     * the default GridView style, or by a call to {@link #setHorizontalSpacing(int)}.
     * If layout is not yet complete or if GridView calculated a different horizontal spacing
     * from what was requested, this may return a different value from
     * {@link #getHorizontalSpacing()}.</p>
     *
     * @return The currently requested horizontal spacing between items, in pixels
     *
     * @see #setHorizontalSpacing(int)
     * @see #getHorizontalSpacing()
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_horizontalSpacing
     */
    public int getRequestedHorizontalSpacing() {
        return mRequestedHorizontalSpacing;
    }

    /**
     * Set the amount of vertical (y) spacing to place between each item
     * in the grid.
     *
     * @param verticalSpacing The amount of vertical space between items,
     * in pixels.
     *
     * @see #getVerticalSpacing()
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_verticalSpacing
     */
    public void setVerticalSpacing(int verticalSpacing) {
        if (verticalSpacing != mVerticalSpacing) {
            mVerticalSpacing = verticalSpacing;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the amount of vertical spacing between each item in the grid.
     *
     * @return The vertical spacing between items in pixels
     *
     * @see #setVerticalSpacing(int)
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_verticalSpacing
     */
    public int getVerticalSpacing() {
        return mVerticalSpacing;
    }

    /**
     * Control how items are stretched to fill their space.
     *
     * @param stretchMode Either {@link #NO_STRETCH},
     * {@link #STRETCH_SPACING}, {@link #STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM}, or {@link #STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH}.
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_stretchMode
     */
    public void setStretchMode(int stretchMode) {
        if (stretchMode != mStretchMode) {
            mStretchMode = stretchMode;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public int getStretchMode() {
        return mStretchMode;
    }

    /**
     * Set the width of columns in the grid.
     *
     * @param columnWidth The column width, in pixels.
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_columnWidth
     */
    public void setColumnWidth(int columnWidth) {
        if (columnWidth != mRequestedColumnWidth) {
            mRequestedColumnWidth = columnWidth;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the width of a column in the grid.
     *
     * <p>This may not be valid yet if a layout is pending.</p>
     *
     * @return The column width in pixels
     *
     * @see #setColumnWidth(int)
     * @see #getRequestedColumnWidth()
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_columnWidth
     */
    public int getColumnWidth() {
        return mColumnWidth;
    }

    /**
     * Return the requested width of a column in the grid.
     *
     * <p>This may not be the actual column width used. Use {@link #getColumnWidth()}
     * to retrieve the current real width of a column.</p>
     *
     * @return The requested column width in pixels
     *
     * @see #setColumnWidth(int)
     * @see #getColumnWidth()
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_columnWidth
     */
    public int getRequestedColumnWidth() {
        return mRequestedColumnWidth;
    }

    /**
     * Set the number of columns in the grid
     *
     * @param numColumns The desired number of columns.
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_numColumns
     */
    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        if (numColumns != mRequestedNumColumns) {
            mRequestedNumColumns = numColumns;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of columns in the grid. 
     * Returns {@link #AUTO_FIT} if the Grid has never been laid out.
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#GridView_numColumns
     * 
     * @see #setNumColumns(int)
     */
    @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
    public int getNumColumns() {  
        return mNumColumns;
    }

    public ExpandableListAdapter getInnerAdapter() {
        return ((ExpandableGridInnerAdapter)getExpandableListAdapter()).mInnerAdapter;
    }

    private boolean determineColumns(int availableSpace) {
        final int requestedHorizontalSpacing = mRequestedHorizontalSpacing;
        final int stretchMode = mStretchMode;
        final int requestedColumnWidth = mRequestedColumnWidth;
        boolean didNotInitiallyFit = false;

        if (mRequestedNumColumns == AUTO_FIT) {
            if (requestedColumnWidth > 0) {
                // Client told us to pick the number of columns
                mNumColumns = (availableSpace + requestedHorizontalSpacing) /
                        (requestedColumnWidth + requestedHorizontalSpacing);
            } else {
                // Just make up a number if we don't have enough info
                mNumColumns = 2;
            }
        } else {
            // We picked the columns
            mNumColumns = mRequestedNumColumns;
        }

        if (mNumColumns <= 0) {
            mNumColumns = 1;
        }

        switch (stretchMode) {
        case NO_STRETCH:
            // Nobody stretches
            mColumnWidth = requestedColumnWidth;
            mHorizontalSpacing = requestedHorizontalSpacing;
            break;

        default:
            int spaceLeftOver = availableSpace - (mNumColumns * requestedColumnWidth) -
                    ((mNumColumns - 1) * requestedHorizontalSpacing);

            if (spaceLeftOver < 0) {
                didNotInitiallyFit = true;
            }

            switch (stretchMode) {
            case STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH:
                // Stretch the columns
                mColumnWidth = requestedColumnWidth + spaceLeftOver / mNumColumns;
                mHorizontalSpacing = requestedHorizontalSpacing;
                break;

            case STRETCH_SPACING:
                // Stretch the spacing between columns
                mColumnWidth = requestedColumnWidth;
                if (mNumColumns > 1) {
                    mHorizontalSpacing = requestedHorizontalSpacing + 
                        spaceLeftOver / (mNumColumns - 1);
                } else {
                    mHorizontalSpacing = requestedHorizontalSpacing + spaceLeftOver;
                }
                break;

            case STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM:
                // Stretch the spacing between columns
                mColumnWidth = requestedColumnWidth;
                if (mNumColumns > 1) {
                    mHorizontalSpacing = requestedHorizontalSpacing + 
                        spaceLeftOver / (mNumColumns + 1);
                } else {
                    mHorizontalSpacing = requestedHorizontalSpacing + spaceLeftOver;
                }
                break;
            }

            break;
        }
        return didNotInitiallyFit;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
            if (mColumnWidth > 0) {
                widthSize = mColumnWidth + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
            } else {
                widthSize = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
            }
            widthSize += getVerticalScrollbarWidth();
        }

        int childWidth = widthSize - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        determineColumns(childWidth);
    }

    private class ExpandableGridInnerAdapter implements ExpandableListAdapter {

        private final ExpandableListAdapter mInnerAdapter;

        private ExpandableGridInnerAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter adapter) {
            this.mInnerAdapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return mInnerAdapter.getGroupCount();
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            int realCount = mInnerAdapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition);

            int count;
            if (mNumColumns != AUTO_FIT) {
                count = realCount > 0 ? (realCount + mNumColumns - 1) / mNumColumns : 0;
            } else {
                count = realCount;
            }   

            return count;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return mInnerAdapter.getGroup(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return mInnerAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return mInnerAdapter.getGroupId(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return mInnerAdapter.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
        }

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) (convertView != null ? convertView : new LinearLayout(getContext()));

            if (row.getLayoutParams() == null) {
                row.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, AbsListView.ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_IGNORE));
                row.setPadding(0, mVerticalSpacing / 2, 0, mVerticalSpacing / 2);
                row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            }

            int groupChildrenCount = mInnerAdapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition);

            int index = 0;
            for (int i=mNumColumns * childPosition; i<(mNumColumns * (childPosition + 1)); i++, index++) {
                View child;

                View cachedChild = index < row.getChildCount() ? row.getChildAt(index) : null;

                if (i<groupChildrenCount) {                 
                    if (cachedChild != null && cachedChild.getTag() == null) {
                        ((ViewGroup)cachedChild.getParent()).removeView(cachedChild);
                        cachedChild = null;
                    }

                    child = mInnerAdapter.getChildView(groupPosition, i, i == (groupChildrenCount - 1), cachedChild, parent);
                    child.setTag(mInnerAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, i));
                } else {
                    if (cachedChild != null && cachedChild.getTag() != null) {
                        ((ViewGroup)cachedChild.getParent()).removeView(cachedChild);
                        cachedChild = null;
                    }

                    child = new View(getContext());
                    child.setTag(null);
                }

                if (!(child.getLayoutParams() instanceof LinearLayout.LayoutParams)) {
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
                    if (child.getLayoutParams() == null) {
                        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mColumnWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
                    } else {
                        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mColumnWidth, child.getLayoutParams().height, 1);
                    }

                    child.setLayoutParams(params);
                }

                child.setPadding(mHorizontalSpacing / 2, 0, mHorizontalSpacing / 2, 0);

                if (index == row.getChildCount()) {
                    row.addView(child, index);
                } else {
                    child.invalidate();
                }
            }

            return row;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            mInnerAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            mInnerAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return mInnerAdapter.areAllItemsEnabled();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return mInnerAdapter.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
            mInnerAdapter.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
            mInnerAdapter.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
        }

        /*@Override
        public long getCombinedChildId(long groupId, long childId) {
            return mInnerAdapter.getCombinedChildId(groupId, childId);
        }

        @Override
        public long getCombinedGroupId(long groupId) {
            return mInnerAdapter.getCombinedGroupId(groupId);
        }*/

        public long getCombinedChildId(long groupId, long childId) {
            return 0x8000000000000000L | ((groupId & 0x7FFFFFFF) << 32) | (childId & 0xFFFFFFFF);
        }

        public long getCombinedGroupId(long groupId) {
            return (groupId & 0x7FFFFFFF) << 32;
        }
    }
}
```

Corresponding attrs.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="ExpandableGridView">
        <attr name="horizontalSpacing" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="verticalSpacing" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="stretchMode">
            <enum name="none" value="0"/>
            <enum name="spacingWidth" value="1" />
            <enum name="columnWidth" value="2" />
            <enum name="spacingWidthUniform" value="3" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="columnWidth" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="numColumns" format="integer" min="0">
            <enum name="auto_fit" value="-1" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Comment: @snuk182 Can give me any example how i can use your class `ExpandableGridView` to create ExpandableGridview .

Comment: A bit late, sorry. Here is it.
https://github.com/snuk182/aceim/blob/master/Ace%20IM/src/aceim/app/view/page/contactlist/GridContactList.java
https://github.com/snuk182/aceim/blob/master/Ace%20IM/src/aceim/app/view/page/contactlist/GridContactListAdapter.java
https://github.com/snuk182/aceim/blob/master/Ace%20IM/src/aceim/app/view/page/contactlist/DoubleContactList.java
https://github.com/snuk182/aceim/blob/master/Ace%20IM/src/aceim/app/view/page/contactlist/DoubleListAdapter.java

Comment: This code is not working. I have tested. It's working as a simple ExpandableListView. ChildView is not gridview

Comment: @shantanu, child view should not be a single monolithic GridView, because it can be only fully purged while hidden. if it contains a lot of items, all of them are maintained by inner GridView's adapter, which in the end turns into unpredictable items layout and management. This is because GridView is not designed to be used as non-scrolling layout within scrollable host (you can find lots of complains here at SO). There are TableLayout and GridLayout, though, but neither of them meets the requirement of row-wise item lifecycle management.

Comment: If you have a better solution with GridView, please show it. I admit that my code has flaws (one at least - using compound layouts instead of direct drawing to canvas - had little experience for doing that way).

Answer (score 1):

instead of using multiple expandable gridviews you could use this library https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders, in which you can put one adapter with one gridView (the custom StickyGridHeadersView), and manage the different headers with specific view handlers for each kind of header/grid-element

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example of [Expandable RecyclerView](https://github.com/Armani2015/expandable-recyclerview-with-gridlayout) . It provides an Expandable RecyclerView with group items that can be individually expanded to show its children in a two-dimensional scrolling grid. Each grid item can be selected.