# how to implement Expandable Gridview in android

Tags: android, android-gridview

How to implement the `ExpandableGridView` in android don't have any idea how to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is ExpandableGridView?

Comment: This link can also help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875903/expandable-gridview-with-view-recycling-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You can simply follow this example.

1) https://github.com/madhu314/sectionedgridview

2)https://gist.github.com/sakurabird/6868765